# How do you make in Orientdb the edge to be unique

Tags: orientdb

How do I make a Edge unique in Orientdb.

The solution that I came up with:

- delete the edge
- create it again

but it's not nice. 
Edge is without any properties.

**Example:**

```
create edge is_friend from #12:0 to #12:3
```

and if I call it again, there should be an error like when you make a unique index.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Create a constraint on Edge out and in fields. For more information:

http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Schema.html#constraints

In your case try this:

```
CREATE INDEX UniqueEdges ON is_friend (out, in) unique
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand from the doc how to make an EDGE unique. The examples are for the Vertex class.. [i have no problem with making a field unique for vertexes, it's easy...]. I've updated my answer with a picture if it helps...

Comment: I get com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexException: Index with name : 'UniqueEdges' cannot be created on class : 'is_friend' because field: 'out' is absent in class definition.

Comment: Right, create both properties "in" and "out" in class "is_friend".

Comment: Ok... what type should those be ?

Comment: in and out are both LINK

Comment: What if the direction of the link is not important? For instance in the above case if we consider friendship a two-way relationship, we can say that out=#1:1, in=#1:2 and out=#1:2, in=#1:1 can be considered redundant.

Comment: @retrography This kind of constraint is not supported, but seems a cool feature to add. Could you please open a new issue in https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue

Comment: @Lvca Actually I gave this a little bit of thinking since this comment. The issue is more general: How should we treat undirected edges in OrientDB? The only logically sound and viable solution is two save them as two directed edges. If we can define a constraint on edge classes that turns them into non-directional edges, and saves them as a pairs of directed edges, then the conditions for the above constraint will always be respected. Maybe I have to open an issue for undirected edges, if there isn't already one.