# Why are my edges returning content rather than RIDs?

Tags: graph-theory, orientdb, graph-databases

I have noticed some of my edges are saved in a strange format.

Here is an example:

```
orientdb {db=gems}> select out_Authored from developer where ghid = 399335 unwind out_Authored

----+------+---------------------------------------------------------------
#   |@CLASS|out_Authored
----+------+---------------------------------------------------------------
0   |null  |#17:312286
1   |null  |#17:312288
2   |null  |Authored{date:2012-03-25 02:51:07 UTC,out:#47:1,in:#49:306155}
3   |null  |Authored{date:2012-11-21 00:41:12 UTC,out:#47:1,in:#49:369448}
4   |null  |Authored{date:2012-11-20 22:41:01 UTC,out:#47:1,in:#49:369449}
5   |null  |Authored{date:2011-11-30 21:09:09 UTC,out:#47:1,in:#49:666948}
6   |null  |Authored{date:2012-03-25 02:51:07 UTC,out:#47:1,in:#49:2096436}
7   |null  |Authored{date:2012-05-23 20:39:31 UTC,out:#47:1,in:#49:2682556}
8   |null  |Authored{date:2012-05-23 20:39:31 UTC,out:#47:1,in:#49:2733007}
----+------+---------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you see, only the two first two edges are listed with their RID, while the others return the content rather than the RID. Now if I ask explicitly for the RIDs, I get the following:

```
orientdb {db=gems}> select out_Authored.@rid from developer where ghid = 399335 unwind out_Authored

----+------+------------
#   |@CLASS|out_Authored
----+------+------------
0   |null  |#17:312286
1   |null  |#17:312288
2   |null  |#-1:-1
3   |null  |#-1:-1
4   |null  |#-1:-1
5   |null  |#-1:-1
6   |null  |#-1:-1
7   |null  |#-1:-1
8   |null  |#-1:-1
----+------+------------
```

First I thought some of the edges had been saved as lightweight edges or links, but then I noticed that if I directly query the concerned edge class for those edges that return an RID of -1, I actually receive a response that shows the edges exists and its RID is not -1:

```
orientdb {db=gems}> select from Authored where in=#49:306155 and out=#47:1

----+----------+--------+-----+----------+-----------------------
#   |@RID      |@CLASS  |out  |in        |date
----+----------+--------+-----+----------+-----------------------
0   |#17:555831|Authored|#47:1|#49:306155|2012-03-25 02:51:07 UTC
----+----------+--------+-----+----------+-----------------------
```

What is happening to my database, and how can I fix it?

### Addendum:

I found out why this has happened. At some point in time I decided I needed to impose a uniqueness constraint on the edge, and I did so as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27768489/1840412) by @Lvca. Those broken edges are the ones created after this modification. You can find the class description below.

Although I have found the culprit, I still don't know how to fix the data, and moreover, how to impose the edge uniqueness constraint without getting these catastrophic results.

```
orientdb {db=gems}> info class Authored

CLASS 'Authored'

Super classes........: [E]
Default cluster......: authored (id=17)
Supported clusters...: authored(17)
Cluster selection....: round-robin
Oversize.............: 0.0

PROPERTIES
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
 NAME                          | TYPE        | LINKED TYPE/CLASS             | MANDATORY | READONLY | NOT NULL |    MIN    |    MAX    | COLLATE  |
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
 in                            | LINK        | Commit                        | false     | false    | false    |           |           | default  |
 out                           | LINK        | Developer                     | false     | false    | false    |           |           | default  |
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+

INDEXES (1 altogether)
-------------------------------+----------------+
 NAME                          | PROPERTIES     |
-------------------------------+----------------+
 Authored.in_out               | in (+)         |
                               | out            |
-------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you show the result of `select from [#17:312286,#17:555831]`?

Comment: Which version of OrientDB?
How do you create edges?

Comment: The latest. That would be 2.1.4 I guess.

Comment: @wolf4ood I updated the question with new info. Any idea how I can fix this mess?

Comment: @neRok This is the result: `0 |#17:312286|Authored|2011-11-09 23:28:07 UTC|#47:1|#49:175427`. I also added some fresh info to the question. Any further idea?

Comment: You might need to drop and recreate your edges. Some info [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Using-schema-with-graphs.html): `The index returns tells us that no entries are indexed. You have already created the Onws relationship between Luca and the Ferrari Modena. In that case, however, OrientDB had created a Lightweight Edge before you set the rule to force the creation of documents for Owns instances. To fix this, you need to drop and recreate the edge.`

Comment: @neRok I have tried dropping and recreating. The problem is that as long as the schema is present, I get those corrupted edges. The correct edges were all created prior to imposing the schema. Plus, this document must be really outdated. It's been a while since Lightweight edges have been disabled by default. At least on my database they are disabled by default.

Comment: @retrography how can i reproduce this state?

Comment: I've got no real answer, but the "broken" edges actually look like embedded objects to me. Could be a bug in orient where the type is interpreted as EMBEDDED, then they won't get a recordId. On such a wrong insert, I find it easiest to debug into the orient code. My guess is that you can find the problem within the code that determines the type of the field when inserting a vertex/document/edge. This is only useful if you have knowledge and/or are using Java.

Comment: @wolf4ood i think this is the result of a wrong interaction between active-orient and the fact that i defined schema for my ingoing/outgoing links. but i am unable to reproduce it on other datasets. probably a rare bug.

Comment: @Wouter you are definitelty right. that is my conclusion. i know java but it probably faster if i recreate the edges. although there are more than 10 millions...